# Created a list, but getting errorTypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() in python

Tags: python, list, nonetype

I'm getting TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() when I try to run main.py. Variable blobs is initialized in blob.py as None, but is later defined in adamEve() as a list. When I try to run main.py, I get this error within the for loops of hungerManage(). Thank you for the help.

Blob.py

```
from random import seed
from random import randint

seed(2)
blobs = None
class Blob:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = randint (0, 1000)
        self.gender = randint(0, 1)
        self.age = 0
        self.ate = False
        newSeed = self.name*self.gender
        seed(newSeed)
def adamEve():
    global blobs
    blobs = [Blob() for _ in range(2)]
    print(blobs)
    blobs[0].gender = 0
    blobs[1].gender = 1
def debug():
    for x in range(len(blobs)):
        print("Name: ", blobs[x-1].name, ", ", "Gender:", blobs[x-1].gender)
```

Food.py

```
food = 0

def foodSupply(amount):
    global food
    food = amount
```

hungerManage.py

```
from Blob import *
from Food import *

def hungerManage():
    global blobs
    global food
    for x in range(len(blobs)):
        if food > 0:
            blob[x].ate = True
            food = food - 1

        if food <= 0:
            blob[x].ate = False

    for x in range(len(blobs)):
        if blob[x].ate == False:
            del blob[x]
```

main.py

```
from Blob import *
from Food import *
from hungerManage import *
adamEve()
foodSupply(50)
debug()
hungerManage()
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: your debug function doesn't have `global blob` in it. That may be the cause of the issue

Comment: You are abusing global variables here, which is the root of all your problems.

Comment: @Jab absolutely not the cause of it.